# Defer with two pairs of brackets

Tags: core-language

I found this in a Mathematica file :

```
Defer[Int][(d+e*x^n)^q*(a+b*x^n+c*x^(2*n))^p,x]
```

where Int a function defined with multiple rules like these :

```
Int[(a_+b_.*x_^n_+c_.*x_^n2_.)^p_.,x_Symbol] :=
  Int[x^(2*n*p)*(c+b*x^(-n)+a*x^(-2*n))^p,x] /;
FreeQ[{a,b,c},x] && ZeroQ[n2-2*n] && RationalQ[n] && n<0 && IntegerQ[p]


Int[(a_+b_.*x_^n_+c_.*x_^n2_.)^p_,x_Symbol] :=
  With[{k=Denominator[n]},
  k*Subst[Int[x^(k-1)*(a+b*x^(k*n)+c*x^(2*k*n))^p,x],x,x^(1/k)]] /;
FreeQ[{a,b,c,p},x] && ZeroQ[n2-2*n] && FractionQ[n]


Int[(a_+b_.*x_^n_+c_.*x_^n2_.)^p_,x_Symbol] :=
  x*(2*a+b*x^n)*(a+b*x^n+c*x^(2*n))^p/(2*a) /;
FreeQ[{a,b,c,n,p},x] && ZeroQ[n2-2*n] && ZeroQ[b^2-4*a*c] && Not[IntegerQ[p]] && ZeroQ[n*(2*p+1)+1]
```

According to the documentation Defer is defined with only one pair of bracket.
So what does this mean ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without knowing what `Int` is exactly I cannot elaborate on what intentions the author of your file had. Nevertheless, while indeed `Defer` , according to the documentation, is called with one argument, consider

```
f[x_]:=x^2
```

Then one can do

```
f[2]
```

> 4

but

```
Defer[f][2]
```

> f[2]

which seems to be the same as

```
HoldForm[f[2]]
```

> f[2]

but if you copy, paste and run the output of `Defer[f][2]` you'll get `4`, while if you copy, paste and run the output of `HoldForm[f[2]]` you'll get `f[2]`.

Comment: One thing to note, the output of `HoldForm[f[2]]` **has the `HoldForm` in it, but hidden**. It can be seen by running `HoldForm[f[2]] // FullForm`. Thus, you must `ReleaseHold` prior to using the output of `HoldForm[f[2]]`.